# Wrap the content in div

Tags: html, css

I need to wrap my content in a div automatically when the content exceeds the width of the div.

How can i use css to make the content fit to div without using scrollbar.

Here is my Code :

```
<div id="main">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <blockquote>
        <p>content content content content</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#main ul li blockquote p
{
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

How can i do this ?

Comment: Are you sure your code is correct? Your CSS selector isn't going to match any element in the HTML you pasted.

Comment: Venator welcome to StackOverflow. I've rolled back the edit to your code as it made understanding the question difficult as it appeared there was no error in the code at all. When people recommend solutions to code, you shouldn't edit the answer to remove the errors as that makes it difficult for future users to understand the context of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

First off, as pointed out by @esqew, your selector is not correct. You probably want:

```
#main ul li blockquote p
```

---

To make any element resize to fit its content, use the `auto` value for CSS height:

```
#main ul li blockquote p
{
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    height: auto;
}
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QY4H2/)